# SQL How can this happen? - Query which normally returns 1 result alone actually resulted in multiple results when put inside WHERE clause

Tags: sql

#### Question brief

I'm doing this practice on [w3resource](https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-joins-exercise-25.php) and I couldn't understand why the solution worked. I'm 2 days old to SQL. I'll appreciate very much if someone can help me explain.

I have 2 tables, COMPANY(com_id, com_name) and PRODUCT(pro_name, pro_price, com_id). Each company has several products with different prices. Now I need to write a query to display companies' name together with their most expensive products respectively.

The sample answer on the practice is like this

```
SELECT c.com_name, p.pro_name, p.pro_price
FROM product p 
INNER JOIN company c ON p.com_id = c.com_id 
      AND p.pro_price = 
           ( SELECT MAX(p.pro_price) 
             FROM product p 
             WHERE p.com_id = c.com_id );
```

The query returned expected result.

```
com_name    pro_name     pro_price
---------   ---------    -----------
Samsung     Monitor      5000.00
iBall       DVD drive    900.00
Epsion      Printer      2600.00
Zebronics   ZIP drive    250.00
Asus        Mother Board 3200.00
Frontech    Speaker      550.00
```

But I cannot understand how, especially the part inside the bottom sub-query. Isn't SELECT MAX(p.pro_price) supposed to return only 1 highest price of all companies together?
I also tried subsecting this sub-query like this

```
SELECT MAX(p.pro_price)
FROM product p 
INNER JOIN company c ON p.com_id = c.com_id 
WHERE p.com_id = c.com_id;
```

... and it only returned 1 maximum value.

```
max(p.pro_price)
-----
5000.00
```

So how does the final result of the whole query include more than 1 records? There's no GROUP BY or anything.

By the way, the query seemed to use 2 conditions for INNER JOIN. But I also tried swapping the 2nd condition into a WHERE clause and it still worked the same. This is one more thing I don't understand.

#### The databases involved

**COMPANY table**

```
COM_ID | COM_NAME
----------------
11     | Samsung
12     | iBall
13     | Epsion
14     | Zebronics
15     | Asus
16     | Frontech
```

**PRODUCT table**

```
PRO_NAME              PRO_PRICE  COM_ID
-------------------- ---------- ---------
Mother Board          3200        15
Key Board             450         16
ZIP drive             250         14
Speaker               550         16
Monitor               5000        11
DVD drive             900         12
CD drive              800         12
Printer               2600        13
Refill cartridge      350         13
Mouse                 250         12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sub-query is a **correlated sub-query**. This query is executed for each value of c.com_id in the outer query:

> `WHERE p.com_id = c.com_id`